# How to Group By in Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have record data structure in the BQ, when i run the following query my output is as follow:

```
Query : SELECT v.key, v.value from table unnest(dimensions.key_value) v;

key    value
region  region1
loc     location1
region  region1
loc     location1
region  region2
loc     location2
```

Now i want to do group by using `region` and `location` so my output will be as follow:

```
groupBy              Count

region1,location1     2
region2,location2     1
```

If i need to do group by using only one key then it would be a simple query:

```
SELECT v.key, count(*) from table, unnest(dimensions.key_value) v group by v.key;
```

But how to do for more than one key ?

Comment: your question missing important info - what makes region1 and location1 to be grouped together? why not region1 and location2?! obviously in your example you can think you can rely on `N` in `regionN` and `locationN` - but for sure this is not what you can do with real data  - right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe pivot it first?

```
with pivotted as (
  select 
    (select value from t.dimensions.key_value where key = 'region') as region,
    (select value from t.dimensions.key_value where key = 'loc') as loc
  from table t
)
select region, loc, count(*)
from pivotted
group by region, loc
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . You seem to be assuming that the *ordering* of the values is important.  This is not a good way to store repeating pairs of data -- arrays of structs seems better.  But you can use `with offset` and some arithmetic.

Assuming that region and loc are the only values and they are interleaved (as in your example):

```
with t as (
       select struct(array[struct('region' as key, 'region1' as value),
                   struct('loc', 'location1'),
                   struct('region', 'region1'),
                   struct('loc', 'location1'),
                   struct('region', 'region2'),
                   struct('loc', 'location2')
                  ] as key_value) as dimensions
       )
select rl.region, rl.loc, count(*)
from (select (select array_agg(region_loc) as region_locs
              from (select struct(max(case when kv.key = 'region' then kv.value end) as region,
                                  max(case when kv.key = 'loc' then kv.value end) as loc
                                 ) as region_loc
                    from unnest(dimensions.key_value) kv with offset n
                    group by floor( n / 2 )
                   ) rl2
              ) as region_locs
      from t
     ) rl3 cross join
     unnest(rl3.region_locs) rl
group by 1, 2;
```